# Should the worker also need Hadoop installed for Spark?

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I have setup scala,Hadoop & spark & started the master node successfully. 
I just installed scala & spark & started the worker(slave) too. So what I am confused is shouldn't Haddop be setup in worker too for running tasks?

Comment: So actually someone answers your question. You don't accept the answer and yet you change your question completely. If you have a new question, please post it as a new question and don't change the question title and details.

Comment: sorry, I edited to avoid duplication, but the second part of the answer is about building spark, which require hadoop. But my both questions were regarding if Hadoop is essential for both Master & worker. Later I was able to run worker without Hadoop. That caused confusion & thus I edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html) link from the official Apache Spark shows how to configure a spark cluster. And the requirements are clearly explained [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html) that both scala and hadoop are required.

Comment: The second link you provided is about building spark, which I don't intend to. I've used the complied version of spark on master. I installed only scala & spark & tried starting worker which was successful.